# Throwing Error at disparity in StereoBM method

Tags: python, opencv

I am using a fisheye camera for depth image. I had tried with StereoSGBM() method for the depth map which has not given the desired results but now I am trying it with StereoBM() method.

> ```
> stereoMatcher = cv2.StereoBM() preset = 2 ndisparities = 32 WinSize = 5
>
> if not left.grab() or not right.grab():
>     print("No more frames")
>     break
>
> _, leftFrame = left.retrieve()
> #leftFrame = cropHorizontal(leftFrame)
> leftHeight, leftWidth = leftFrame.shape[:2]
> _, rightFrame = right.retrieve()
> #rightFrame = cropHorizontal(rightFrame)
> rightHeight, rightWidth = rightFrame.shape[:2]
>
>
> if (leftWidth, leftHeight) != imageSize:
>     print("Left camera has different size than the calibration data")
>     break
>
> if (rightWidth, rightHeight) != imageSize:
>     print("Right camera has different size than the calibration data")
>     break
>
> fixedLeft = cv2.remap(leftFrame, leftMapX, leftMapY,   REMAP_INTERPOLATION)
> fixedRight = cv2.remap(rightFrame, rightMapX, rightMapY, REMAP_INTERPOLATION)
>
> grayLeft = cv2.cvtColor(fixedLeft, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> grayRight = cv2.cvtColor(fixedRight, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> ```

As compute a function of StereoBM() also needs a third argument as disparity. I calculated it by using

> ```
> grayLeft = cv2.cvtColor(fixedLeft, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> grayRight = cv2.cvtColor(fixedRight, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
> disparity = stereoMatcher.compute(grayLeft, grayRight)
> depth = stereoMatcher.compute(grayLeft, grayRight)
>
>
> #cv2.imshow('left', fixedLeft)
> #cv2.imshow('right', fixedRight)
> cv2.imshow('depth', depth / DEPTH_VISUALIZATION_SCALE)
>
> if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
>     break
>
> left.release() right.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows()
> ```

But it is throwing an error which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fisheye_depth.py", line 104, in <module>
    disparity = stereoMatcher.compute(grayLeft, grayRight)
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'StereoMatcher' or its derivative)
```

If anyone has any idea about it that what mistake I am doing. Let me know what mistake I am doing taking out the disparity for compute operator().

Comment: Try `StereoBM_create` instead of `StereoBM`

Comment: I want to add the `FISH_EYE_PRESET=CV_STEREO_BM_FISH_EYE ` value given in [link](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.5/org/opencv/calib3d/StereoBM.html) with 
 **StereoBM** which I am not able to do with  **StereoBM_create**

Comment: So it means that you have OpenCV 2, because `StereoBM`'s presets like `FISH_EYE_PRESET` were removed in OpenCV 3.0. You should add this in your question.